# Como abrir una app desde mi página web

Tags: php, javascript, bootstrap

Como abrir una app desde mi Website al pulsar un botón cuando está este siendo visualizada desde un dispositivo móvil.

La website ha sido desarrollada con Html5, Bootstrap 4, PHP, Javascript, y Jquery/Ajax.

La App ha sido desarrollada con Angular, Ionic, y Cordova, esta ya se encuentra en la Playstore de Google, así que no debería haber inconvenientes de seguridad.

Comment: A ver si entendi. Quieres haber una aplicacion android desde tu pagina web?

Comment: Lo que entiendo es que tienes una página web que visitas desde tu movil y desde allí quieres llamar una App que esta descargada en el mismo  movil

Comment: @JheymanMejia es correcto

Comment: Puedes revisar [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958701/launch-custom-android-application-from-android-browser) en SO (inglés), pero primero te recomiendo tomes un tiempo para que apliques a tu proyecto la respuesta de @JCAguilera y comentarle si tienes dudas sobre el avance

Answer (score 3):

Puedes abrir una url con tu app usando [Deep Links](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/deeplinks/) en tu aplicación. Esto es, dada una url, en vez de abrirse en el navegador, se abrirá con tu aplicación, y dirigirá al usuario a una sección específica de ésta.

Con Ionic sería asi:

```
import { Deeplinks } from '@ionic-native/deeplinks/ngx';

constructor(private deeplinks: Deeplinks) { }

this.deeplinks.route({
     // A que sitio dirigen las URLs:
     '/about-us': AboutPage,
     '/universal-links-test': AboutPage,
     '/products/:productId': ProductPage
   }).subscribe(match => {
     console.log('Ruta encontrada! ', match);
   }, nomatch => {
     console.error('No existe un deeplink para esta url: ', nomatch);
   });
```

Esto también puede lograrse con Android Nativo de esta manera:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.android.GizmosActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_gizmos" >
    <intent-filter android:label="@string/filter_view_http_gizmos">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <!-- Aceptar URIs que empiecen con "http://www.example.com/gizmos” -->
        <data android:scheme="http"
              android:host="www.example.com"
              android:pathPrefix="/gizmos" />
        <!-- nota que el "/" anterior a "gizmos/" es requerido por pathPrefix-->
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter android:label="@string/filter_view_example_gizmos">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <!-- Aceptar URIs que empiecen con "example://gizmos” -->
        <data android:scheme="example"
              android:host="gizmos" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

En este ejemplo, en la app se abrirán las URLs que empiecen con `http://www.example.com/gizmos` y `example://gizmos`.

Aquí el enlace a la documentación para Ionic (inglés): https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/deeplinks/

Y para android nativo (inglés): https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking

Comment: Creo que el titulo de la pregunta es "Abrir desde web una App" y no "Abrir desde App una Web" ¿?

Comment: Si, eso hacen los deep links. Esto es que una url, en vez de abrir una web, abra una app.

Comment: _"...la app abrirá las URLs"_ Siento insistir, pero tu mismo lo mencionas. No conozco la solución a la pregunta y tampoco sabría como hacerlo, pero es un tema de comprensión de lectura jajaja es que me rayo un poco

Comment: Si se mal entiende un poco, debe ser la diferencia de español, voy a internacionalizarlo un poco.

Comment: @JheymanMejia lo he editado para mejorar más la comprensión. Espero se entienda ahora.

Comment: @JCAguilera gracias por la respuesta aunque lo que necesito es abrir una aplicación desde mi sitio web el cual ha sido desarrollado en PHP y Javascript. a lo cual no encuentro la utilidad requerida actualmente.